# No method named `par_iter` found for type

Tags: rust, rayon

I am trying to parallelize the following iter call using the rayon crate

https://github.com/vishpat/stl/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L315

and replace the iter call with par_iter but get the following compile error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `par_iter` found for type `std::vec::Vec` in the current scope
   --> src/lib.rs:221:28
    |
221 |             self.triangles.par_iter().map(|triangle| triangle.calculate_normals());
    |                            ^^^^^^^^
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: you have impl `pub fn iter(&self) -> TriangleIterator` for Model, but i don see any definition of `iter_mut`.

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty iter_mut  is being called over triangles which is a Vec<Triangle> and not the model that contains the Vec

Answer (score 3):

As you probably already know [rayon](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon#using-rayon) crate has to be added to `Cargo.toml` and declared into `lib.rs`.

Then add the prelude into your `mod parser`, not into the root crate:

```
pub mod parser {

    use std::fs::File;
    use std::io::Read;
    use std;
    use rayon::prelude::*;
```

Finally, you have a mutable iterator, use a `par_iter_mut`:

```
    model.triangles.par_iter_mut().for_each(|triangle| triangle.calculate_normal());
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That did it.